# Updating a column based on other 2 column's values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have user_contents table. Here is the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `user_contents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_contents_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
)
```

order_id is the newly added column. I need to update values of order_id based on the values of content_type and user_id. content_type can be 0 or 1.

[image: Expected Result]

Based on content_type and user_id i have to update order_id as shown in the above result. For same user_id and content_type order_id need to be incremented from 0.

Can some one help me with the update query

I am using **mysql** db of version **5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1**

**Edit : -** - Now the requirement is slightly changed. Instead of data_type int for user_id, it is changed to varchar holding values like DAL001, HAL001 etc

Comment: What have you attempted so far ? This is a Window function problem. But in MySQL 5.7, you will have to utilize User defined session variables.

Comment: Hi I need to write update query. My expected result is shown in the image. Stuck in developing update query of field order_id

Comment: Don't have a column that is the result of other columns. Create a view instead. (Or at least use triggers to handle the column updates.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query, to update `order_id` values. This employs [User-defined session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

This query basically consists of two parts. First part determines `order_id` for every `id`, based on the defined logic.

Second part joins with the `user_contents` table using `id` and updates the `order_id` values.

```
UPDATE user_contents AS uc 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    dt.id, 
    @oid := IF(@uid = dt.user_id AND 
               @ct = dt.content_type, 
               @oid + 1, 
               0) AS order_id, 
    @uid := dt.user_id, 
    @ct := dt.content_type 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      user_id, 
      content_type
    FROM user_contents 
    ORDER BY user_id, content_type
  ) AS dt 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @oid := 0, 
                     @uid := 0, 
                     @ct  := 0) AS user_init_params 
) AS dt2 ON dt2.id = uc.id 
SET uc.order_id = dt2.order_id
```

Comment: Don't you need the order by in the same scope as the variable manipulation?

Comment: @matbailie technically, that might be right, but practically (except when using rand()), it seems to make no difference

Comment: @MatBailie I am already using `order by user_id, content_type` in the innermost select. This is why I have got 2 sub-selects

Comment: Yes, and then you wrap another query around it in which you manipulate the variables.  SQL doesn't guarantee the order would be maintained in such a situation.  Thus, I asked; Don't you need the order by in the ***same*** scope as the variable manipulation?  *(Your response was to say you have the order by in a **different** scope, nested one level deeper than the variable manipulation.)*

Comment: @MatBailie ok now I understand your concern. I believe that **MySQL** does ensure that the order is maintained in results obtained from a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) . So far, I have not observed any other behaviour while using subselects (derived tables) in MySQL. Otherwise, there is no other way to emulate complex Window function like functionality; because `select` list is processed first and then `order by`

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya for the reply. One more doubt. If user_id is varchar type what all modifications should i do in above query

Comment: @SeenaVP you wil need to use `CAST user_id AS UNSIGNED`. It would be better if you do alter table and change it to `int`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I cant change the type. Now the requirement is like user_id column include characters also like DAL01, HTQ01 etc

Comment: @SeenaVP just change to `@uid := ''` in `user_init_params`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Tried that but no luck . Shows error like ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AAT8651'

Comment: Got it Thanks a lot @MadhurBhaiya. You saved me

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use a view to achieve what you want.  Here is one option which should work without window functions and without sessions variables:

```
CREATE VIEW user_contents_view AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        user_id,
        content_type,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_contents uc2
         WHERE uc2.user_id = uc1.user_id AND
               uc2.content_type = uc1.content_type AND
               uc2.id < uc1.id) order_id
    FROM user_contents uc1
);
```

[image]

### Demo

The main problem with suggesting to do an update here is that the `order_id` column apparently is *derived* data.  This would mean that you might have to more updates again in the future.  So, a view avoids this problem completely by just generating the output you want when you actually need it.

Comment: I would go one step further and say that, because of the `main problem` that you describe, doing this at all is probably an indication that they're doing something that they shouldn't *(a so-called code-smell)*.  I think that if they described ***why*** they want to do this and ***how*** it will be used, better / cheaper alternatives could be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
string SQL = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM user_contents 
WHERE user_id = 'label1' AND content_type ='label2'";

string sql = "UPDATE user_contents SET order_id='" +bb+ "' WHERE sl='1'";
```

After getting maximum order id increment the orderid and pass to some variable and update using update query.